# Magento 2 + How Delete 50 products with images in a single time with creating custom consumer::queue?

Tags: magento2, product, message-queue, queue, consumers

I have **1lac** **products** in Magento, I **want to delet**e the products based on some condition like if the product is disabled, but if we **delete all products** in a single time using corn the **server can crash**. I searched and came to know that many people suggested the **consumer::queue**. Is it a better way for my purpose?

**How can I delete 50 products with images in a single time by creating a custom consumer::queue?**

If anyone has **any idea** or **example** please **share**, How do **create a custom consumer::queue** to delete 50 products once and then delete the other 50 until all 1lac products are deleted?

**I need a custom consumer::queue example to delete some products with images.**

Comment: I think deleting the 50 products in a single time is not a big deal. The issue can be your code which causes the performance issue. Queue is a better solution, but please check your code logic first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Import Behavior in Import Product functionality

[image]

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your help but i need to create a custom consumer:queue, any example you have?